# How to fix Indeterminate TOP 1 result from SQL select union

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am selecting an int value from two different tables as shown below

```
select col1 from tablea
union 
select col1 from tableb
```

The requirement is if result is found in first query, use that; otherwise, look in second table.

```
select top 1 * from (select col1 from tablea union select col1 from tableb) as a
```

Problem is the highest numerical value of the result set is returned as `top 1` - not the first result found.

I don't care about the numerical value as in it's order - I just want to apply precedence to if find a value from select 1 don't bother to run second query.

Without the `top 1 *` I get returned `3` and `6`.  When I do `top 1 *` I get `6` and same result if I do the other select first.

Help!

Comment: Do both tables always only return one value? If not, there **has** to be some sort order on both tables to know what values from tablea to match with values from tableb.

Comment: is there any relationship between two tables(like foreign key)...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you UNION these two selects the order IS NOT DEFINED you can think of it as a RANDOM order. So you should define order to get right results. For example:

```
select top 1 C1 from 
(select col1 as C1, 1 as c2 from tablea 
     union 
 select col1 as C1, 2 as c2 from tableb) as a 
ORDER BY C2
```